# Sorting kaltura base entry list by name

Tags: android, kaltura

I am requesting katura base media entry list using `base entry` service and action as `list`.
I am trying to sort base entry media list by name as below:

```
KalturaMediaEntryFilter filter = new KalturaMediaEntryFilter(); 
filter.typeIn = "1"; 
filter.orderBy = KalturaMediaEntryOrderBy.NAME_DESC.toString(); 
KalturaMediaListResponse listResponse = mediaService.list(filter);
```

But "orderBy" element does not have any effect on the results, I tried multiple combination, but getting same results.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using media service and not baseEntry.
Second, you should check what's in 'KalturaMediaEntryOrderBy.NAME_DESC'. eventually, the value of filter.orderBy should be '-name'.

Comment: I have given media service just for example, can you please provide example to how to sort it by name?

Comment: I don't know what client library you're using so i don't know what's in KalturaMediaEntryOrderBy.NAME_DESC. you can do this:
filter.orderBy="-name"

Comment: I am using kaltura Android Client library the latest version and my server is kaltura CE latest. can you please explain what is the issue in my code (code provided in question) why my result is not sorting as per the sort order?

Comment: Did you try the filter.orderBy="-name" as @Alon Brimer suggested ?